# IIS7 CGI standard input blocking with large input rather than setting EOF

Tags: c++, iis-7, cgi

I am writing a C++ CGI application to run on IIS7.  My problem is that when the volume of data sent to a POST request gets over a certain size, reading from standard input blocks forever, rather than setting EOF.  I suspect this is not a C++ specific issue.  I have already successfully configured the server to run a "hello world" type application which I am now extending to do something useful, so I do not feel it is a fundamental mis-configuration.

The most trivial application to illustrate the problem is as follows.  The application halts on the call on the commented line (I have attached the debugger to the process running under IIS to prove this).

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::stringstream input_text;
    input_text << std::cin.rdbuf(); // application halts here

    std::cout << "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have found various people discussing the same issue but no resolution e.g.

- [similar issue](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/12/13/how-to-run-cgi-applications-on-iis7.aspx) (look for the string 'It seemed that IIS7 was not filling STDIN "immediately" and if I just did a "readfile" of the whole expected number of bytes, some windows thread was getting "stuck" somewhere.)'
- [similar issue with Python CGI](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-February/569439.html)